# What should I be concerned about on this house?

Tags: basement, sump-pump

Please see:
[Is channel in basement standard design?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/162485/is-channel-in-basement-standard-design/162512#162512)

[image: 8 to 12 inches of water in basement]

I'm concerned the first block course is being used as a permeable tile when it's not designed as permeable.

Is water heater or furnace destroyed?

Is outside ground saturation too much for septic system?

Side and back of house have mini ponds. (standing water on ground) It hasn't been raining that much.  Other side of house has some kind of stream or drainage trench with minimal water in it.  There is a swamp hehind properly according to Google Earth.

Septic system is in front yard.  No visible issues in front yard at ground level.

Well may be shallow dug well in backyard.

Comment: I'd be concerned by its dual-purpose as a swimming pool.

Comment: Yes, I told the agent that the swimming pool addition was unrequested and please remove it.  Pump out tomorrow.  Furnace is maybe ok?  Gas water heater destroyed?  I'm more concerned that the basement is not stable, 1st course is used as permeable drain tile without actually being permeable block

Comment: I'd actually be more worried about the furnace than the water heater. The electronics in an older ordinary tank aren't much. But "everything" in the furnace can get easily ruined by flooding - control board, fan motor, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is far too broad a question for our format. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: A better picture would be helpful I have a crappy phone but even looking on my computer can't quite understand the question. Neither the water heater or furnace is ruined by a couple of inches of water but it may shorten there useful life span.